# BJT reverse base-emitter voltage 1 Volts?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio

Using the multimeter diode setting in a powered down circuit, on the TR6 transistor (BC548), the forward B-E and B-C voltages are ~0.7 V, reverse B-C is OL but reverse B-E is 1.08V.

Does this mean the transistor is bad, or can it be a consequence of measuring in circuit and due to the neighboring components?

All other transistors (TR1-TR5) have ~0.7V forward voltages and OL when measured in reverse on both junctions.

[image: Schematic]

PS: this is related to and somewhat the complement of yesterday's question, when I asked if correct measurements in-circuit guarantee a working transistor.

Comment: thanks. I may have to remove it and measure it if there's no other conclusive way...

Answer (score 0):

It does not mean that the transistor is bad.

It only means that the multimeter, using the way it uses to measure in the diode mode, is able to push enough current that voltage is 1.08V.

And you don't know unless you remove it from the other circuits for measuring.

When you try to measure the emitter-base Veb, there are two leakage paths.

One is obviously the total resistance of 1330 ohms directly between the B and E nodes.

The other is via the zener diode. As effectively 12V is at 0V when power is not applied, -1.08V at base means that the zener should not conduct much.

Basically, it would be far easier to just measure voltages when the circuit is powered.

Comment: Thanks. You mean measure the E-B voltage using the V setting on the multimeter when the circuit is powered on?

Are the other transistors in the circuit showing OL correctly because their neighbors interfere less with the measurement?

Comment: All other transistors have higher impedances around them, and they are of different type as well. And we don't know how your multimeter measures things in diode mode. You didn't even tell the multimeter make and model for us to figure it out.

Comment: I didn't think the multimeter type mattered. It's an Amprobe 35 XP-A.

Comment: The manual says to free up at least one diode leg before measuring. It is necessary to get sane readings. The make and model is not important but it just says how the measurement is performed. The diode test mode measures how much is the voltage when it tries to push 1.2 mA of current to the circuit. The no-load voltage is 3V. So it is clear that the other components on board will affect the measurement.

Comment: Thanks. So in circuit measurements aren't conclusive.